# How can I put something like this in a Smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty, templating

I am trying to convert a pre-existing site that had html and php intermingled into a Smarty template based site. I never used Smarty before so this is proving very difficult for me. I get that you can assign a variable like so:

```
$smarty->assign('number_of_items_in_cart', $number_of_items_in_cart);
```

and use it in the tpl file like so:

```
{$number_of_items_in_cart}
```

but what about more complex things like this block of code that I had on the old site:

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$pid' ");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        extract($row);
        echo "<h2>$name</h2>";
        echo "<img src='images/product_images/$image' alt='' width='100' />";
        echo $description;
        echo '<p>'.money($price).'</p>';
        echo "<input type='text' value='1' class='qty-$id' />";
        echo "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick=\"add_cart('$id')\">Add to Cart</a>";
    }

} else {
    redirect('404.php');
}
```

How can I work with this in a Smarty template, since the output is within a while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of echoing this, you can append it in a string variable  then pass it to smarty:

```
$string = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        extract($row);
        $string .= "<h2>$name</h2>";
        $string .=  "<img src='images/product_images/$image' alt='' width='100' />";
        $string .=  $description;
        $string .=  '<p>'.money($price).'</p>';
        $string .=  "<input type='text' value='1' class='qty-$id' />";
        $string .=  "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick=\"add_cart('$id')\">Add to Cart</a>";
    }
```

Now u can pass it to smarty

```
$smarty->assign('place_holder', $string);
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: this works, but overall I think templating is stupid. I just have to learn it for work, maybe my opinion would change later when I learn more but at first impression it just seems unnecessary and time consuming.

Comment: i understand you, but when you want to separate your code, and not mix html and php it makes sense. for example, let's say you want to have a designer and a developper work together, the designer will be overwhelmed with all the code and will have a hard time making the slightest changes. but with templating, it makes it easy to separate php and the html so one doesnot have to know how the other works

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `foreach` builtin function to iterate over an array containing your query results.
You could also use `foreachelse` to display an alternate message (though in this case you're redirecting).

See example 7.9 in http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach .

**Edit:** there's also a [while](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.while.tpl) function if that's what you really want.